# Python питон не видит библиотеки

Tags: python

У меня питон 3.11 скачивал keyboard и mouse с помощью pip install в командной строке было написано тип всё ок а когда запускаю код ошибка, в visual studio выставлена среда python 3.11

Вот код:[image]

Вот ошибка:[image]

Comment: А устанавливали библиотеки точно в ту же среду, что выбрана?

Comment: а как это делать помогите

Comment: @CrazyElf А как скачать иммено в среду?

Comment: Ну, запустить pip3 из каталога, где он именно в этой среде лежит

Comment: @CrazyElf написал pip3 install pyspeedtest уже попробовал с другой библиотекой всеравно не работает. Через Интерпретатор написал import pyspeedtest выдало такуюже ошибку как у keyboard

Comment: Где именно написали pip3, в каком каталоге? )

Comment: @CrazyElf Написал pip3 в командной строке вот так pip3 install keyboard написало всё ок. А в интерпретатор ввёл import keyboard. В итоге такаяже ошибка. Пытался через файл .py запускать все равно не работает

Comment: В каком каталоге вы были, когда вводили pip3 в командной строке? Нужно быть в каталоге правильного окружения

Comment: @CrazyElf А как выбрать правильное окружение для pip3? В visual studio я выбрал питон

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score -1):

Нашёл ответ! Если у вас такая ошибка попробуйте в интерпретаторе ввести
import pip и после этого вот эту команду:
[image]Мне помогло все работает!

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)